# how to migrate Open cart to magento site

Tags: magento-1.9

I have opencart website i wanna be a convert into  magento. if anybody have idea to migrate site opencart to magento please give me a feedbacks thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a of magento extension is available  in magento  community.Which is migate opencart to magento

1.http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cart2cart-opencart-to-magento-migration.html

Comment: Thanks but this is paid extension..

Comment: yes.it paid extension...

Comment: i want to be free extension or module if you have..

Comment: no... i  have not any extension in  free

Comment: check this link free module for opencart :-http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=16064

Comment: above @AmanDhiman..it is not free..."Module is free to install, nonetheless data migration service itself is paid - starting from $69 per migration. "